# Change template so XSLT Outputs a sum instead of a list of values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT template that is working fine.

```
  <xsl:template match="Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="BenefitList/Row/Premium* 12" />
    </value>
  </xsl:template>
```

The output is

```
<value>100</value>
<value>110</value>
```

What I would prefer is if it would just output `220`.  So, basically in the template I would need to use some sort of variable or looping to do this and then output the final summed value?

XSLT 1 compliance is required.

The template is being used as follows:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]" />`

For some reason, when I use the contains here it only sums the first structure that matches and not all of them.  If The XML values parent wasn't dependent on having a sibling element that matched a specific value then a'sum' approach would work.

Comment: Use the sum() function. No looping is required.

Comment: That won't work.  The template writes out each element, so if I put sum it will do a sum but only on the current element and thus the results won't be any different.

Comment: Your template is being called twice. Use the `sum()` function as @michael.hor257k suggested in the context that calls your template.

Comment: For each match is will trigger my xsl-value-of

Comment: I have edited my question and provided details of why that didn't work.  I had tried that before posting the question.  Because I am using contains="" to find elements it only finds the first one and does a sum on that value.

Comment: Please post a **complete** (reproducible) example, including your XML input, XSLT and expected output. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I thought I had seen this before. I actually did, and even answered it! Doesn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24048087/3190413) solve your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT sum is concatenated instead or summed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047735/xslt-sum-is-concatenated-instead-or-summed)

Comment: @helderdarocha Looks like a loop *is* necessary after all... :-)

Comment: @michael.hor257k It seems to be a duplicate of a duplicate, since you answered this already a week ago :D

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8t/1 and the linked question, where I added some more information.

Comment: @helderdarocha Ah. I see that [I have indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897188/xslt-1-compliant-code-to-get-sum-of-elements-when-there-is-a-parent-value-match). OP likes to plant but not to harvest?

Comment: My intention was that this was a different question as it was related to how to accomplish looping/variables in the template specifically without changing the XSLT that was applying the template.  Sorry for any confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct solution to the problem was already mentioned in the comments, but assuming you really want to do the same with some variables, this might be interesting for you:

XML:

```
<Root>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>MyBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>100</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>MyBenefit, OtherBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>100</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>OtherBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>1000</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>OtherBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>1000</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <total>
            <xsl:variable name="valuesXml">
                <values>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]" />
                </values>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="values" select="exsl:node-set($valuesXml)/values/value" />

            <xsl:value-of select="sum($values)" />
        </total>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]">
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="BenefitList/Premium * 12" />
        </value>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here the same result set generated in your question is saved in another variable, which can then again be processed.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That's what I was asking in the question, where as the related question solved the problem of doing it without the other template.  Thanks!